# How to find the source code for printf in C?

Tags: c, printf

I am curious to know what is inside the `printf` function.

Is there any command in terminal or cmd, to get the source code for that function?

Comment: So you want to _see_ the source code, not _executing_ it...

Comment: Many standard libraries have their source available. If you tell us what compiler you're using and for what platform then we could tell you where to find the source. But note that most implementations will be very hard to read and understand for beginners.

Comment: You might start at https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/printf.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply right click on the printf and see the full code describing it.

```
    _Check_return_opt_
_CRT_STDIO_INLINE int __CRTDECL printf(
    _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ char const* const _Format,
    ...)
#if defined _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE
;
#else
{
    int _Result;
    va_list _ArgList;
    __crt_va_start(_ArgList, _Format);
    _Result = _vfprintf_l(stdout, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);
    __crt_va_end(_ArgList);
    return _Result;
}
#endif
```

Here is how you do it in visual studio :
[image: printf]

Answer (score 4):

The exact source code for standard library functions will vary between implementations - that is, the source for the `*printf` family will be different for gcc, LLVM, the Visual Studio compiler, etc.  Not every implementation makes their source code available.

Having said that, the source code for the GNU C library (glibc) can be found [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc).  Again, this is only one of many different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

This is roughly what it contains:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void minprintf(char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap; 
    char *p, *sval;
    int ival;
    double dval;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    for(p = fmt; *p; p++) {
        if(*p != '%') {
            putchar(*p);
            continue;
        }
        switch (*++p) {
            case 'd':
                ival = va_arg(ap, int);
                printf("%d", ival );
                break;
            case 'f':
                dval  = va_arg(ap, double);
                printf("%f", dval);
                break;
            case 's':
                for(sval = va_arg(ap, char *); *sval; sval++)
                    putchar(*sval);
                break;
            default:
                putchar(*p);
                break;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap); 
}
```

An example is taken from the book "C language".
Book written by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.
You will find detailed explanations of C language and other standard functions there.

Comment: Perhaps see also P.J. Plauger's _The Standard C Library_

Answer (score 0):

It called reverse engineering, and you can use tools like `IDA` and `Ghidra` for that.

Another thing you can do is to look on the internet for an open-source version of the implementation of the function, like from `Linux`, for example [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/printf.c).

Answer (score 0):

most of the times you see that you have to include some headers in your c program in order to use some functionalitis, for example any time that you want to use printf function you need to use stdio.h. so in stdio.h you could see a function that has been defined called
printf. pay attention that in some headers files there might be other files included , so if you can't see the complete definition of a function , look in other headers that has been defined there, but every function that you have ever used in you c program has been defined in one of the headers in either one of these directories in linux:

/usr/include

/usr/include/linux