# Fprintf implementation in C

Tags: c

Hi I want to write base implementation of `fprintf` function in C. I have problem with the void cast. It says that it is incompatible type for argument 2 of `write`. I tried several ways to do it but nothing changes.
Thats the function :

```
void myfprintf(int fd, char *format, void *value) {
    if(strcmp(format,"%d")){
        write(fd,(*(int*)value),sizeof(int));
    }
    if(strcmp(format,"%f")){
        write(fd,(*(float*)value),sizeof(float));
    }
    if(strcmp(format,"%lf")){
        write(fd,(*(double*)value),sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

For start I want to print int double and float types.

Comment: First of all, `write` writes a sequence of bytes, and it uses a *pointer* to the first byte. So no cast is needed. ***But*** that will lead to another problem, namely that you write the raw in-memory binary representation of the values, instead of converting it to a textual representation.

Comment: Aside: format `%f` is `double` not `float` (unlike the`scanf` functions). There is no `float` format in the variadic function that `fprintf` is, where it is promoted to `double`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811188/how-to-find-the-source-code-for-printf-in-c

Comment: Yes i fix the cast but now says �@free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Also, if you really want to make a "fprintf"-like function, find a book or tutorial that explains *variable argument functions* and how they work.

Comment: There seems to be little point having a function like this where the format string can only be say `"%d"` with no newline, spacing or anything else. Why not just have one function for each type and forget about the overhead of an unnecessary format string?

Comment: One step at a time. First make your function to work using `sprintf("%d", *(int*)value);` etc. Once that work, write your own equivalent for converting data to text for `write`.

Comment: You could start "formatting" and seeing the results if `fd` was `stdout` (your screen)... It's one thing to convert an integer type to a string of digits... Converting a double to a string is rocket science and brain surgery combined..

Answer (score 1):

To implement an fprintf-like function you should declare your function with ellipsis,

```
int myprintf(int fd, char *format, ...);
```

then use the so called 'var_args' (variable arguments) tools to access argument.  See the manual pages on va_start(), va_arg(), va_end().
These tools are macros that properly walk the values and pointers on your stack. The stack arrangement is machine-architecture and implementation dependent, and those dependencies are hidden in the var args macro implementation.

You'll find examples here:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-opt/nldbl-compat.c;h=2b1261acc7505d9a6ac3f25b76bafb9118854ef8;hb=HEAD